# "No emulator images (avds) found". Even after creating one

Tags: cordova

I have this issue:

```
Error: No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4/tools/android sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4/tools/android avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver
```

I did already created two emulator images by running `android avd`

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Android Studio open the AVD Manager then create AVD(if not yet created) and launch it in the emulator. Now execute the command ionic run android it will run correctly.